# IntelliJ does not sort Kotlin imports

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-14

When writing Java code, IntelliJ automatically sorts imports by name. However, when importin members in Kotlin, they remain unsorted. Selecting Code → Optimize Imports (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) does nothing.

Here is an example:

```
import kotlin.platform.platformStatic
import java.text.DateFormaty
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty as notEmpty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty as jsonProperty
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull as notNull
import javax.validation.Valid as valid
```

What I'm expecting:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty as jsonProperty
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty as notEmpty
import kotlin.platform.platformStatic
import java.text.DateFormat
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull as notNull
import javax.validation.Valid as valid
```

I'm using IntelliJ 14.0.2 with the Kotlin plugin (version 0.10.195)

Comment: Your observation is correct. This functionality hasn't been implemented yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4789

Comment: This issue has been resolved according to YouTrack.

Comment: @JaysonMinard seems it's still not resolved or am I missing something?

Comment: @miensol did you update the Kotlin plugin?

Comment: I feel this should be closed, but I can't find a correct reason. It's basically just a bug in InteliJ, it's not a problem that you can just correct yourself.

Comment: This question is old, and not really applicable except to people using a perpetual fallback licence, so it may be best to close/off-topic. I answered it because I was trawling the unanswered Kotlin questions looking for easy ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in [recent versions of IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4789#tab=History), for example the [current version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) (at time of writing 2017.3.3)

If you only have a perpetual fallback licence for the full version of IntelliJ 14 - you could still use the community edition of a more recent version.